# Pyinstaller import error: module not found

Tags: python, pyinstaller, vtk

I am trying to create the exe of a program in python that uses a bunch of modules. Running it from cmd, everything works fine. But when I try to run the exe (created using pyinstaller 4.0), it does not work. I got the error:

`No module named 'vtk.numpy_interface`

I've tried all the following changes on main.spec and in all of them I got the same error:

- vtk.numpy_interface in 'hiddenimports' tag
- ('C:\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\vtkmodules', './numpy_interface/') in 'datas' tag
- 'C:\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\vtkmodule pathex' in 'pathex' tag

My program does not use vtk.numpy_interface. But i found that it is imported by pyvista.core.datasetattributes (in my program I import pyvista).

I'm using python 3.7.6 and vtk 9.0. When I was using vtk 8.9.0 i didnt got this error.

Anyone could helpe me with any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also had issues with VTK 9.0 in regards to pyinstaller, and I'd recommend keeping with `vtk==8.1.2` (available on PyPI) until this is resolved with the next `vtk` release.